# How to send value bigger than 127 in byte Java

Tags: java, byte, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I am working on an Smart Card where there is a method in `javax.smartcardio.CommandAPDU`.

```
CommandAPDU(int cla, int ins, int p1, int p2, byte[] data, int ne)
```

I need to send  data as `byte[]` (5th argument). Now my problem is that, as Java primitive data types are signed the max value of a byte can not exceed 127. I need to send a value bigger than 127. To be precise, the hex value `94` which is equal to 148.

As some solution suggests that we can cast it to integer.

```
byte b = -108;
int i = b & 0xff;
```

I can't do that as the `CommandAPDU();` constructor doesn't take an `[]`. So how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how it is interpreted by the smart card, you could just send the correct negative value. If the smart card interprets value as unsigned, you could for example send -1 for 255.

Comment: The negative value of x94 = d148 = byte -108
If I send this value it doesn't works. I have a working code in .net and it does work with the same implementation. Only difference I could find out after debugging was the difference in value passes to function.

Comment: @AvinashSahu Make sure that the card state and the commands before this command are exactly the same. It is *very* unlikely that this is your issue (I'm now working with smart cards over 13 years, I should have run into it by now, I'm constantly casting and `& 0xFF`ing my byte values).

Comment: @owlstead Even I think so. The binary representation would be same i. e. 10010100. Actually I am doing mutual authentication between two cards using challenge and response method. Where we first restore lets say Card A then set command then we get challenge from card  A which is sent to card B for internal authentication. The internal authentication response is sent to card A for external authentication and vice versa. I am stuck at first external authentication step. As You have worked on smart card for so many years, I am explaining you. I would have shared the code but it's of no use.

Comment: @owlstead because to debug the code you need scosta smart card. :-(

Comment: @AvinashSahu Can't help you with the scosta authentication. I do know that cryptography relies on each and every bit and algorithm to be correct; so there is a large chance that the issue is elsewhere (probably hiding in plain sight).

Comment: @owlstead yeah. Anyway thanks for looking into question and giving your valuable suggestions. :-)

Comment: @owlstead Hello sir, Lets say I am sendig this APDU in my card CommandAPDU(x00, x88, x00, x81, MYDATA, x08); It runs properly and then when I try to get the response from the card using 
CommandAPDU(x00, xC0, x00, x00, " ", x08) . it gives 69 85 error. [Condition of use not satisfied]. Could you please guide me what can be the possible reason for same. if you pass me your mail or skype Id i can explain you in detail. Please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: No, I cannot without more detail (e.g. I don't even know the protocol). This goes beyond the org. question, and I don't do personal support, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You're calculating the APDU with unsigned bytes, while Java uses signed bytes.

It's just a matter of how the data is interpreted, sending -108 to the smart card will be interpreted in exactly the same way as sending 148 from a platform using unsigned bytes. The bit combination is exactly the same.

Java can even do the conversion itself so that you can write the code using unsigned numbers;

```
byte data = (byte)0x94;   // stores -108 in "data", which will be interpreted
                          // as 148 on an unsigned platform
```

Comment: I also thought same. But similar implementation is working in C# but not in java :(

Comment: @AvinashSahu Hard to debug the difference without seeing the code, but I cannot see a reason why it would not send the same value. Could you show the difference in the generated byte array between .NET and Java?

Comment: I understand. Moreover even if I share the code you wont be able to debug it without having the smart cards which I am using.
the byte array in C# is like 
Let me first put the hex data 
0x94,0x10,0x20, 0x20
C# byte array 
158 16 32 32
Java Byte array
-108 16 32 32

Comment: @AvinashSahu The 158 in C# is 0x9e (aka -98), not 0x94 (aka -108).

Answer (score 0):

For long blocks of data, it is probably best to use a hexadecimal encoder/decoder. But be sure that you handle the data as bytes internally (directly decode and don't look back to the hex `String`). The Apache codec library contains a good encoder/decoder, or you can use Bouncy Castle or Guava or use one of the many examples on SO.